# Akka persistent actor - functional approach

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka, actor

I have been trying to implement persistent actor with functional approach - I mean no variables at all. But I have get into troubles :) The below code example doesn't work properly because handlers parameters are not shared between handlers (receiveCommand/receiveRecover).  Both starts with zeros and then overwrites each other - after replaying some events command handler will still be at starting point.

Another issue with this implementation is the fact of handling commands and events in the same place

Is it good practice to do it functional way at all?

```scala
class Item(sku: String) extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
    import Item._
    override def persistenceId: String = sku
    override def receiveCommand: Receive = handler(0, 0)
    override def receiveRecover: Receive = handler(0, 0)

    def handler(quantity: Int, booked: Int): Receive = {
      case Increase(q) =>
        val event = StockChanged(sku, q)
        persist(event)(e => context.become(handler(quantity + e.quantity, booked)))
      case Decrease(q) =>
        val event = StockChanged(sku, -q)
        persist(event)(e => context.become(handler(quantity + e.quantity, booked)))
      case StockChanged(_, q) => {
        context.become(handler(quantity + q, booked))
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what your question is. Please ask a specific question pointing to a specific problem that can be reproduced by someone else that doesn't have your entire code base with them.

Comment: My question is simple, how to implement persistent actor without using variables (to hold its state)

Comment: So the actor is stateless? What is the problem with making your actor stateless?

Comment: No it is not. I want to implement its state as function

Comment: Is the state of the actor represented by that `handle` function you have in there?

Comment: yes, that handler function manages the state. It works perfectly fine with regular actor. But in case of persistent actor things get more complicated (two seperate hanlders that needs to share state)

Comment: In scala, you can override a def using a val, so try `override val receiveCommand: Receive = handler(0, 0); override val receiveRecover: Receive = receiveCommand`. This way, they both refer to the same object. I'm not sure if this what you are after

Comment: It is not gonna work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. The new akka persistance 2.6 just works in functional manner :)

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence.html#event-sourcing

Answer (score 2):

For those who need to use [Classic Persistence](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html) the best approach I could come up with doesn't need actor-wide state but you still need a local `var` though. Then, you can encapsulate the local var in the closure of the recovery handler.

Expanding and cleaning up the incomplete example in the question:

```scala
package item_example

import akka.actor.ActorLogging
import akka.persistence.PersistentActor

object ItemExample {

  case class Increase(quantity: Int)

  case class Decrease(quantity: Int)

  case class StockChanged(id: String, quantity: Int)

  class Item(sku: String) extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
    override def persistenceId: String = sku

    override def receiveCommand: Receive = listening()

    private def listening(quantity: Int = 0): Receive = {
      case Increase(q) =>
        persist(StockChanged(sku, q)) { e: StockChanged =>
          context.become(listening(quantity + e.quantity))
        }
      case Decrease(q) =>
        persist(StockChanged(sku, -q)) { e: StockChanged =>
          context.become(listening(quantity + e.quantity))
        }
    }

    override def receiveRecover: Receive = recovering()

    private def recovering(): Receive = {
      /*
      This is the local var that will be part of the recovery handler's closure.
      The semicolon is needed only so that the below code within parentheses is interpreted as
      a partial function and not a code block parameter for the integer 0.
      You can also just return a new PartialFunction[Any, Unit] but I find this to be nicer.
       */
      var totalQuantity: Int = 0;
      {
        case StockChanged(_, quantity) =>
          totalQuantity += quantity
          context.become(listening(totalQuantity))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The recovery handler will just override the state after each recovered event. This is OK because [recovery is guaranteed to finish before the actor starts consuming events from the mailbox](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html#recovery).

The above works because calling `context::become` in the recover handler does not modify the recovery handler! It only modifies the mailbox handler. As we go through the replayed events we simply replace the mailbox handler after each event. **The recovery handler will be invoked unchanged for all replayed events.**

A sidenote: it is important to distinguish between *commands* sent to the actor and *events* replayed from the persistent store. The question defines two commands: `Increase` and `Decrease`. It also defines one event: `StockChanged`. However, the `receiveCommand` method handles all three. This is a code smell. `receiveCommand` should handle commands, while `receiveRecover` should handle events. I have cleaned up this problem in the solution above.